# How to change theme dynamically from store data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-saga

I'm trying to change the MuiThemeProvider colors dynamically using data from the store (redux). But this data is asynchronous loaded after the render in the App.js, making the color prop unreachable to the theme provider. How can I update the store asynchronously?

````
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import theme from './config/theme'
import configureStore from './store/store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {LocalizeProvider} from "react-localize-redux";
import Router from "./pages/Router";

export const store = configureStore()

class App extends Component {

  render() {
        return (
            <LocalizeProvider>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <Router/>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </Provider>
            </LocalizeProvider>
        );
  }
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
  const jssStyles = document.getElementById("jss-server-side");
   if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
        jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles); }
}
render() {
   return (
<Provider store={store}>
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
   );   
 }
 }
```